# PlatformPlugin exception getting app-only token using MSAL in ASP.NET Core

Tags: azure-ad-msal

I'm trying to create an ASP.NET Core app that uses MSAL for the client credentials flow.

I get the following exception when trying to get an access token:

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.PlatformPlugin.LoadPlatformSpecificAssembly()
```

Authentication is modeled after this sample: [active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect-aspnetcore-v2](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect-aspnetcore-v2)

Authorization is modeled after this sample: [active-directory-dotnet-daemon-v2](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-daemon-v2)

My app is registered with the Mail.Read Application permission. Here's the code that throws the exception:

```
string authority = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{ tenantId }/v2.0";
ConfidentialClientApplication client = new ConfidentialClientApplication(
    authority,
    appId,
    redirectUri,
    new ClientCredential(appSecret),
    null);//new TokenCache());

AuthenticationResult authResult = await client.AcquireTokenForClient(
    new string[] { "Mail.Read" }, null);
return authResult.Token;
```

Also tried with "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" scope, as in the daemon sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering this question. I opened this as an [issue on the GitHub repo](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/issues/222). It was closed with the following response:

*this problem will not occur with the next release as we will move to a single binary.*